# Dagger with database module

Tags: android, dagger

I am creating a new database module, along with some other feature modules in order to separate the code, maintain work. And the idea is using dagger to create database instance inside database module, and only populate the DAOs object to the feature modules.
Here is my implementation:

The app structure:

```
 -- Application
    |
    -- app module
    |
    -- database module
    |
    -- feature1 modules
    |
    ...
```

Database object:

```
class TestDatabase @Inject constructor (private val context: Context) {

    fun getDao(): TestDao = TestDao()
}
```

Database module:

```
@Module()
class DatabaseModule {

   @Provides
   fun provideDao(database: TestDatabase): TestDao = database.getDao()
}
```

Database component:

```
@Component(modules = [DatabaseModule::class])
interface DatabaseComponent {

     // Only provide the DAO object
    fun dao(): TestDao

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {

        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): DatabaseComponent
    }
}
```

Suppose that the database component only explicit provide the `TestDao` object (not the database instance and other config), and will be initialized at the application level. Then I can use it in the feature component as a dependency.

The application:

```
class TestApplication : Application() {

    private lateinit var databaseComponent: DatabaseComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        databaseComponent = DaggerDatabaseComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
```

The feature component:

```
@Component(modules = [FeatureModule::class], dependencies = [DatabaseComponent::class])
interface FeatureComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun databaseComponent(databaseComponent: DatabaseComponent): FeatureComponent
    }
}
```

I have not tested the code yet, but looks matched with my idea.

But the issue is the DatabaseComponent is created at the Application scope because the database instance should be kept with the app lifecycle, means the DAOs object is also created and alive with the application which doesn't convinced me. I think the DAOs should only go with the feature scope. But not sure how to do that? Is the @Scope can resolve it?

Comment: Post the code of the DAO so it's a bit clearer but why do you need it to be scoped? AFAIK DAOs are pretty much nothing in regards to resources and don't hold any value in them.

Comment: Thanks @TheLibrarian for your comment. The DAO object in my example is just an empty class, cause it just represent a DAO - which doesn't hold any value.
I want it to be scoped because it is still an object, it is created and use memory. And in this large project, my responsibility is also optimize memory, cpu usage.